# On a certain series of cosines

Tags: binomial-coefficients, trigonometric-series

> For natural numbers $p$ and $q$, compute the value of $$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{q-1} \cos^{p}
>  \left(\dfrac{2\pi k}{q}\right).$$

I got the answer $$\dfrac{q}{2^p} \sum_{l=1}^{p} \binom{p}{l} \mathbb{1}_{\{q|p-2l\}}.$$

Here $\mathbb{1}_{E}$ represents the indicator function of the event $E$.

I am hoping that my answer is right. I want to know if there is a closed form expression for my answer.

Comment: Looks like 0 for $p$ odd and $q\frac{2n-1\choose n}{2^{2n-1}}$ for $p=2n$.

Comment: When p > q, there will be more terms. For p < q, you are right.